# Compilation error "expected unqualified-id" when working with templates

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

For my code

```
template Signal<float>;
template Signal<bit_t>;
template Signal<byte_t>;
template Signal< std::complex<float> >;
template Signal< int >;
```

I get compilation errors

```
error at signal_T.cpp:437: error: expected unqualified-id before â;â token
signal_T.cpp:438: error: expected unqualified-id before â;â token
signal_T.cpp:439: error: expected unqualified-id before â;â token
signal_T.cpp:440: error: expected unqualified-id before â;â token
signal_T.cpp:441: error: expected unqualified-id before â;â token
```

What does the compiler want to tell me?

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: (7 years passed...) I found the answer useful, so edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 9):

What is your intent in writing lines such as:

```
template Signal<float>;
```

Are you trying to do explicit template instantiation?  If so, assuming Signal is a class template, you need to change that to:

```
// Instantiate Signal with type float
template class Signal<float>;
```

If you're trying to do something else, please ask a question.